# Rotate model to face direction it's traveling in 3d with scenekit and swift - Boids implementation

Tags: swift, 3d, quaternions, scenekit

I am implementing a boids simulation using Swift and Scenekit. Implementing the simulation itself has been fairly straight forward however I have been unable to make my models faces the direction they are flying (at least all the time and correctly) To see the full project, you can get it here (https://github.com/kingreza/Swift-Boids)

Here is what I am doing to rotate the models to face the direction they are going:

```
func rotateShipToFaceForward(ship: Ship, positionToBe: SCNVector3)
  {
    var source = (ship.node.position - ship.velocity).normalized();

    // positionToBe is ship.node.position + ship.velocity which is assigned to ship.position at the end of this call
    var destination = (positionToBe - ship.node.position).normalized();

    var dot = source.dot(destination)

    var rotAngle = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(acos(dot));
    var rotAxis = source.cross(destination);

    rotAxis.normalize();

    var q = GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndAxis(Float(rotAngle), Float(rotAxis.x), Float(rotAxis.y), Float(rotAxis.z))

    ship.node.rotation = SCNVector4(x: CGFloat(q.x), y: CGFloat(q.y), z: CGFloat(q.z), w: CGFloat(q.w))


}
```

Here is how they are behaving right now

https://youtu.be/9k07wxod3yI

Comment: They look fairly okay in the video, as far as I can tell. Can you be more specific about the problem?

Comment: They look ok at first glance, but if you look, they don't rotate on the Y axis when they are coming or going away from the camera (you never see one facing away or facing toward you when they are moving on the Z axis). @rickster

Comment: @rickster there is something minute missing in my calculations

Answer (score 1):

Three years too late to help the original questioner, and the original YouTube video is gone, but you can see one at the project's [GitHub page](https://github.com/kingreza/Swift-Boids).

The original Boids code stored orientation as  the three basis vectors of the boid’s local coordinate space, which can be thought of as the columns of a 3x3 rotation matrix. Each frame a behavioral “steering force” would act on the current velocity to produce a new velocity. Assuming “velocity alignment” this new velocity is parallel to the new forward (z) vector. It did a cross product of the old up (y) vector and the new forward vector to produce a new side vector. Then it crossed the new side and forward to get a new up vector. FYI, [here is the code for that in OpenSteer](https://github.com/meshula/OpenSteer/blob/master/include/OpenSteer/LocalSpace.h#L291)

Since it looks like you want orientation as a quaternion, there is probably a constructor for your quaternion class that takes a rotation matrix as an argument.

Comment: Thanks @Craig Reynolds! I can't believe you commented on this. I did eventually resolve the issue as the video on the github project reflects the fixed behavior. I don't remember what the issue was but the fix was in this commit. https://github.com/kingreza/Swift-Boids/commit/c0affa91c31ea1d77f4160b190e3ae3115392163#diff-9027a8f3a5019c71d9238de32828e53c